# mercurial default branch disappeared

Tags: mercurial, branch, default, tortoisehg

I've commited a hotfix to a new "hotfix" branch. After this, I merged my branch with "defalt" branch.

Now, I only have the hotfix branch and the default branch disappeared.

How do I change the only one existing "hotfix" branch to "default" with TortoiseHg?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "disappear", that the line in THg closes to the hotfix branch: That doesn't mean the branch is closed.

Just update to the latest default version and commit something. THg marks the head(s) of a branch with a green label, so look for it.

Another posibility is that you have activated the filter toolbar (Ctrl+s). Ensure that there is no filter, everything in the Branch drop-down is deactivated and the Branch-chooser is set to "Show all".

--
If you want to get the changes of your hotfix-branch to the default, update to default and merge it. Then you can close the hotfix-branch (in the commit-dialog).